# Printing with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, printing

I've been looking for hours trying to find a way to print a div containing a Google maps object. I've seen that there are multiple questions here on stack overflow, but none of them seem to be working. My question is this: is there any definitive way to print a google maps file? I'm using custom styles and markers (which need to be printed also). Here's what I've tried so far:

- Using MarkerWithLabel: Only the label is printed
- CSS @media print: The div is too small. When I try expanding the div, the only part of the page loads and the printed image looks really glitchy.
- I can't figure out how to convert a dynamic map to a static URL. I've got custom markers and styles, and I don't know how to convert those to Static Maps' format
- I've tried removing the gmnoprint class, but the markers still don't appear